# Overwrite or append file based on yes or no selection

Tags: java

I am unsure why this will not overwrite or append a premade text file.
I have also tried using 0 and 1 in place of JOptionPane.YES_OPTION and JOptionPane.NO_OPTION but it did not work.

````
import java.io.*; //Import
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WriteToFile6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


    //Variables
        String fileTitle, fileContent;
        int optionSelect;


        fileTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter file name: ", "File4.txt");
        optionSelect = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to overwrite the file content?", "Input", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(optionSelect == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            PrintWriter outputFile= new PrintWriter(fileTitle);
            fileContent = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter content: " ,"Overwrite");
            outputFile.println(fileContent);
        }// selected yes

        else if(optionSelect == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            FileWriter addToFile = new FileWriter(fileTitle, true);
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(addToFile);
            fileContent = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter content ", "Append");
            outputFile.println(fileContent);
        }//selected no


        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cancelled!");
        }//cancel


        

        


    }//Close Main
}//Close Class```
````

Comment: Run your app under the debugger and look at the variables values.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the file. You must use try-with-resources:

```
try (PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fileTitle) {
    fileContent = ..
    outputFile.println....
}
```

Comment: I am unsure how you mean. Could you please explain a little bit more if you dont mind? :)